# Trying to call a element in a tuple thats within a tuple - Python

Tags: python, tuples

```
 def maxTemp(self,k):
    nextDays = self.longforecast[0:k]
    maxx = nextDays([0][0])
    for day in range(len(nextDays)):
      if nextDays[day][0] > maxx:
        maxx = nextDays[day][0]
      elif nextDays[day][1] > maxx:
        maxx = nextDays[day][1]
    return maxx
```

This is one method of my class but the basic object aka self.longestforcast looks something like this:

example = ( (44,57), (44,62), (49,57), (37,59), (45,61) )

its created by with code like:

```
upcoming = LongtermForecast()
upcoming.append(DailyForecast(50,73))
upcoming.append(DailyForecast(48,68))
```

Im trying to access that second number in the DailyForecast object to determine the largest number but run into an error:

```
     21   def maxTemp(self,k):
     22     nextDays = self.longforecast[0:k]
---> 23     maxx = nextDays([0][0])
     24     for day in range(len(nextDays)):
     25       if nextDays[day][0] > maxx:

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the parenthesis, otherwise python tries to use the nextDays as a function, which fails and writes "'tuple' object is not callable".

```
maxx = nextDays[0][0]
```

Comment: Ive tried that when I do so I get the error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That means python is telling you that nextDays is NOT a tuple of tuples and is instead a method. But you said above that it is a tuple of tuples. Insert a print(type(nextDays)) at that spot, better yet, place breakpoint() at that spot and play with the nextDays variable to see what it is.